# Aurelia CLI build to parent folder

Tags: aurelia

I've been trying to get the build (index.html and scripts) to be output to a folder one level above of the project root. 
In my case, something like ../dist/

The goal is to group build files and keep them separated from src files.

I've played with baseDir, baseUrl, index and output paths in Aurelia.json but while the scripts compilation works (scripts are output to the intended location) index.html doesn't get updated with the latest rev filename.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has been bugging me as well, the documentation seems to have some glaring holes. :(

Comment: Hey @VirtualWolf. Haven't spent much time on this since I posted the question. Was hoping someone would provide some guidance. Guess we're two waiting now...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this has been fixed in the docs, but in the     aurelia_project/aurelia.json  I use:

```
"platform": {
"id": "aspnetcore",
"displayName": "ASP.NET Core",
"port": 8080,
"hmr": false,
"open": false,
"output": "wwwroot/dist/"  },
```

The "output" is then used in webpack.config.js

```
const project = require('./aurelia_project/aurelia.json');
const outDir = path.resolve(__dirname, project.platform.output);
```

And in the module.exports

```
 output: {
path: outDir,
publicPath: baseUrl,
filename:  '[name].bundle.js',
sourceMapFilename: '[name].bundle.map',
chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js'
},
 devServer: {
contentBase: outDir,
// serve index.html for all 404 (required for push-state)
historyApiFallback: true
},
```